# What is the analogue of ConcurrentHashMap in Haskell?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, servlets

**update**: please, bear in mind, I'm just started learning Haskell

Let's say we're writing an application with the following general functionality:

- when starting, it gathers some data from an external source;
- this data are a set of complex structures which contain lists,
  arrays, ints, string, etc.;
- when running, the application serves web API (servlets) that provides
  access to the data.

Now, if the application would be written in Java, we could use static ConcurrentHashMap object where the data could be stored (representing Java classes). So that, during start, the app could fill the map with data, and then servlets could access it providing some API to the clients.

If the application would be written in Erlang, we could use ETS/DETS for storing the data (as native Erlang structures).

**Now the question: what is the proper Haskell way for implementing such design?** 
It shouldn't be DB, it should be some sort of a lightweight in-memory something, that could store complex structures (Haskell native structures), and that could be accessible from different threads (servlets, talking by Java-world entities). In Haskell: no static global vars as in Java, no ETS and OTP as in Erlang, - so how to do it the right way (with no using external solutions like Redis)?

Thanks

**update**: another important part of the question - since Haskell doesn't (?) have 'global static' variables, then what would be the right way for implementing this 'global accessible' data keeping object (say, it is  "stm-containers")? Should I initialize it somewhere in the 'main' function and then just pass it to every REST API handler? Or is there any other more correct way?

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-containers-0.2.10/docs/STMContainers-Map.html

Comment: Your update is an entirely separate question, and shouldn't be snuck into this one. The two main approaches are `ReaderT/MonadReader` and `reflection`. `ReaderT/MonadReader` is simpler; `reflection` may be helpful if your "global static" thing turns out not to be so global static once you've gone through more design iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether the client API will provide ways of mutating the data.

If not (i.e., the API will only be about querying), then any immutable data-structure will suffice, since one beauty of immutable data is that it can be accessed from multiple threads safely with you being sure that it can't change. No need for the overhead of locks or other strategies for working with concurrency. You'll simply construct the immutable data during the initialisation and then just query it. For this consider a package like ["unordered-containers"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers).

If your API will also be mutating the data, then you will need mutable data-structures, which are optimised for concurrency. ["stm-containers"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-containers) is one package, which provides those.

Answer (score 6):

First off, I'm going to assume you mean it needs to be available to multiple threads, not multiple processes.  (The difference being that threads share memory, processes do not.)  If that assumption is wrong, much of your question doesn't make sense.

So, the first important point: Haskell has mutable data structures. They can easily be shared between threads. Here's a small example:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    v <- newMVar 0 :: IO (MVar Int)
    forkIO . forever $ do
        x <- takeMVar v
        putMVar v $! x + 1
    forM_ [1..10] $ \_ -> do
        x <- readMVar v
        threadDelay 100
        print x
```

Note the use of ($!) when putting the value in the `MVar`.  `MVar`s don't enforce that their contents are evaluated.  There's some subtlety in making sure everything works properly.  You will get lots of space leaks until you understand Haskell's evaluation model.  That's part of why this sort of thing is usually done in a library that handles all those details.

Given this, the first pass approach is to just store a map of some sort in an `MVar`.  Unless it's under a lot of contention, that actually has pretty good performance properties.

When it is under contention, you have a good fallback secondary approach, especially when using a hash map.  That's striping.  Instead of storing one map in one MVar, use N maps in N MVars.  The first step in a lookup is using the hash to determine which of the N MVars to look in.

There are fancy lock-free algorithms, which could be implemented using finer-grained mutable values.  But in general, they are a lot of engineering effort for a few percent improvement in performance that doesn't really matter in most use cases.